# Whats wrong with my code? Output (Average Female GPA: nan)

Tags: c++

Program reads the following data from a .txt file.

```
f 2.5
m 3.5
f 2.1
f 3.7
m 4.0
f 3.2
f 3.1
f 1.7
f 2.2
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 3.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 2.3
f 3.5
f 3.9
f 3.7
m 4.0
f 2.2
f 2.1
f 1.7
f 2.2
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 4.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 3.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 2.3
f 3.5
f 3.9
f 3.7
m 4.0
f 2.2
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 3.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 2.3
f 3.5
f 3.9
f 3.7
m 4.0
f 2.2
f 2.1
f 1.7
f 2.2
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 4.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 3.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 2.3
f 3.5
f 2.2
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 3.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 2.3
f 3.5
f 3.9
f 3.7
m 4.0
f 2.2
f 2.1
f 1.7
f 2.2
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 4.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 3.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 2.3
f 3.5
f 2.2
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 3.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 2.3
f 3.5
f 3.9
f 3.7
m 4.0
f 2.2
f 2.1
f 1.7
f 2.2
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 4.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 3.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 2.3
f 3.5
f 2.2
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 3.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 2.3
f 3.5
f 3.9
f 3.7
m 4.0
f 2.2
f 2.1
f 1.7
f 2.2
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 4.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 3.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 2.3
f 3.5
f 2.2
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 3.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 2.3
f 3.5
f 3.9
f 3.7
m 4.0
f 2.2
f 2.1
f 1.7
f 2.2
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 4.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 3.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 2.3
f 3.5
f 2.2
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 3.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 2.3
f 3.5
f 3.9
f 3.7
m 4.0
f 2.2
f 2.1
f 1.7
f 2.2
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 4.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 3.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 2.3
f 3.5
f 2.2
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 3.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 2.3
f 3.5
f 3.9
f 3.7
m 4.0
f 2.2
f 2.1
f 1.7
f 2.2
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 4.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 3.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 2.3
f 3.5
f 2.2
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 3.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 2.3
f 3.5
f 3.9
f 3.7
m 4.0
f 2.2
f 2.1
f 1.7
f 2.2
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 4.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 3.6
m 2.1
f 3.5
f 1.9
m 1.7
m 2.3
f 3.5
```

Then calculates the average (gpa) for each gender (m for male, f for female).
but what the program outputs in a new file is:

Average Male GPA: nan

Average Female GPA: nan

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include "string"
using namespace std;

void openFiles(ifstream& inData, ofstream& outData)
    {

    inData.open("cpga.txt");
    outData.open("avggpa.txt");

    outData << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);        
} 

void initialize (int& countFemale, int& countMale,
               float& sumFemaleGPA,float& sumMaleGPA,
               float& avgMaleGrade, float& avgFemaleGrade)
{

 countFemale=0;
 countMale=0;
 sumFemaleGPA=0;
 sumMaleGPA=0;
 avgMaleGrade=0;
 avgFemaleGrade=0;
 } 


void sumGrades(int& countFemale, int& countMale, float& sumFemaleGPA, 
               float& sumMaleGPA)
{

     char gender;
     float gpa;


           if(gender == 'm')
              {
                         sumMaleGPA += gpa;
                         countMale++;   
              }         

     else if (gender == 'f')
              {
                      sumFemaleGPA += gpa;
                      countFemale++;
              }

}

void averageGrade (float& avgMaleGrade, float& avgFemaleGrade, float sumMaleGPA, int countMale, float sumFemaleGPA, int countFemale)
{

    avgMaleGrade = sumMaleGPA / countMale;

    avgFemaleGrade = sumFemaleGPA / countFemale;

}

void printResults(float avgMaleGrade, float avgFemaleGrade, ostream &outData)
{
    outData << "Average Male GPA: " << avgMaleGrade << endl;
    outData << "Average Female GPA: " << avgFemaleGrade << endl;    

}



int main()
{

char gender;
    float gpa, sumFemaleGPA, sumMaleGPA, avgMaleGrade, avgFemaleGrade;
    ifstream inData;
    ofstream outData;

    int countFemale, countMale;

    initialize (countFemale, countMale, sumFemaleGPA, sumMaleGPA, avgMaleGrade, avgFemaleGrade);

    openFiles(inData, outData);

    sumGrades(countFemale, countMale, sumFemaleGPA, sumMaleGPA);

    averageGrade (avgMaleGrade, avgFemaleGrade, sumMaleGPA, countMale, sumFemaleGPA, countFemale);

    printResults(avgMaleGrade, avgFemaleGrade, outData); 


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

inData.close();
outData.close();

}
```

Can anybody spot whats wrong with this code? Cheers!

Comment: your initialize function does nothing to initialize the floats that are passed by reference.

Comment: Can you please post the after edited version here? Thanks!

Comment: nan stands for "Not A Number" by the way...

Comment: I left you an answer, there are quite a few things that are going wrong semantically (ignoring the poor coding style). you are making too many function calls for incredibly simple tasks.

Answer (score 4):

there are quite a few things wrong here:

first of all in your initialize function you are not initializing any of the floats passed by reference.
instead you may want to do this:

```
void initialize (int& countFemale, int& countMale,
               float& sumFemaleGPA,float& sumMaleGPA,
               float& avgMaleGrade, float& avgFemaleGrade)
{

 countFemale=0;
 countMale=0;
 sumFemaleGPA=0;
 sumMaleGPA=0;
 avgMaleGrade=0;
 avgFemaleGrade=0;
 }
```

additionally, in your sumGrades function you have :

```
 while( inData >> gender >> gpa )
 {

    inData >> gender >> gpa;
    ....
```

you are losing half of your input because you are rewriting new values immediately after the while loop. instead you should get rid of the `inData >>gender >>gpa` inside the while block and just use gender and gpa.

edit: your function should look like this:

```
 void sumGrades( ifstream& inData, int& countFemale, 
       int& countMale, float& sumFemaleGPA, float& sumMaleGPA)
{

 char gender;
 float gpa;

 while(inData>> gender>>gpa)
 {
       if(gender == 'm')
          {
                     sumMaleGPA += gpa;
                     countMale++;   
          }         

 else if (gender == 'f')
          {
                  sumFemaleGPA += gpa;
                  countFemale++;
          }
    }
}
```

moreover, you open input and output file streams but you do not close them. this is not good.

there is also no reason for you to have istream and ostream parameter types for your sumGrades function when your stream types are ifstream and ofstream file streams.

fix all of these issues and comment back if it is still not working

Comment: Thanks alot for such a detailed reply! Much appreciated bro!

Comment: Made all the changes but still the same output.                                                                                           Average Male GPA: nan
Average Female GPA: nan

Comment: simplify your code, print out what you are reading from the file.  use a debugger (like gdb on linux) to trace your program. provide a minimal complete verifiable example.

Comment: Ok i've edited it completely.Also added the input file and output i'm getting.

Comment: no, you wrecked your sumGrades function, I didnt say get rid of the inputting completely, I said take out the redundant one

Comment: I have provided your sumGrades function, if you fix it It should work

Comment: Still the same result :/ have you got teamviewer? Its my marked assignment. Really want this to work.

Comment: I tested here and the code worked with output: Average Male GPA: 2.60
Average Female GPA: 2.82

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm still getting the same output.

Comment: get rid of system("PAUSE"); and move the stream closes before you return from main

Comment: Still the same output in the "avggpa.txt" file. Is there a problem in my compiler? I'm using Dev.

Comment: i doubt it, make sure the name of input file matches what you have. use cout statements inside the getSum function to output the genders and marks you are getting

Comment: The name of file is the same. "nan" output still appearing.

Comment: you should pick a best answer

Answer (score 3):

There are many things that can be improved here

First, rather than have functions to do an action on many things, it is the common practice in C++ to group these functions per thing into a `class`

Second, there is no need to create functions whose sole purpose is to take code out of `main` and call them only once

Third, there is no need to have all those variables.

Fourth, personally I prefer `double` to `float` because unless there are serious space concerns and precision is verified, `double`s avoid many rounding issues.

Fifth, please refrain from utilizing `using namespace std;` spelling it out is much clearer and will not cause issues if you move code to common `include` files.

Sixth, please explicitly close files you open.

Seventh, use include files

Here is a the way I would have attempted this:

Include file ***GradeCategory.h***:

```
#ifndef GRADE_CATEGORY_H
#define GRADE_CATEGORY_H
#include <iostream>

class GradeCategory
{
public:
        GradeCategory() : total(0.0), count(0) {
        }
        void add(double grade) {
                total+=grade;
                count++;
        }
        double average() const {
                return total/count;
        }
        friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& S, const GradeCategory& rhs) {
                return S << rhs.average();
        }
private:
        double total;
        int count;
};
#endif
```

And here is the ***main.cpp*** file:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "GradeCategory.h"

int main() {
    std::ifstream inData;
    inData.open("cpga.txt");

    GradeCategory map[256];

    unsigned char gender;
    double gpa;

    while( inData >> gender >> gpa ) {
        map[gender].add(gpa);
    }

    inData.close();

    std::ofstream outData;
    outData.open("avggpa.txt");

    outData << std::fixed << std::showpoint << std::setprecision(2);

    outData << "Average Male GPA: " << map['m'] << std::endl;
    outData << "Average Female GPA: " << map['f'] << std::endl;

    outData.close();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed reply.Well it's a college assignment so we only had to put use to the basics.

Comment: This answer was not just for you, but to help anyone who comes here to learn.   I am not attempting to do your homework, I am intending to help teach how to think about C++.

Comment: added slight tweak to improve performance, note that on some extremely small stack environments a smartpointer to a heap allocated array instead of an array allocated from the stack may still be needed but I felt that overkill for this answer